# How to store data-attr value in an SCSS variable?

Tags: sass

I have HTMl link `<a href="#" class="cta-link" data-label="Change well"></a>`.

I need to store `data-label` in SCSS variable like `$string:attr('data-label');`. Is it possible?

Comment: Is your question how to target a tag with a `data-label` attribute or how to set it with Sass?

Comment: @Mario Tacke: Neither, their question is how to store the value of an attribute in a Sass variable. (To which the answer is "you can't".)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, Is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because your SCSS/SASS is compiled into CSS before being delivered to your browser. So your browser (where your html and css is parsed) doesn't know anything about SCSS/SASS at all.